# Explaining the approximation to the variational free energy in Bayes by Backprop

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian, monte-carlo, bayesian-network

In the paper [Weight Uncertainty in Neural Networks, Blundell et al., 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05424), the authors approximate the exact cost (variational free energy)

$$
\mathcal F(\mathcal D, \theta) = \mathrm{KL}[q(\mathbf w \vert \theta) \mathrel{\|} P(\mathbf w)] - \mathbb E_{q(\mathbf w \vert \theta)}[\log P(\mathcal D \vert \mathbf w)] \tag{1}
$$
with the approximation
$$
\mathcal F(\mathcal D, \theta) \approx \sum_{i=1}^n \log q(\mathbf w^{(i)} \vert \theta)  - P(\mathbf w^{(i)})  - \log P(\mathcal D \vert \mathbf w^{(i)}) \tag{2},
$$

"where $\mathbf w^{(i)}$ denotes the $i$th Monte Carlo sample drawn from the variational posterior $q(\mathbf w^{(i)} \vert \theta)$."

This appears to be a (simple) Monte Carlo estimate but why isn't there included a $\frac 1n$ normalizing term for the expectation estimate, i.e. why isn't the correct approximation:
$$
\mathcal F(\mathcal D, \theta) \approx \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \log q(\mathbf w^{(i)} \vert \theta)  - P(\mathbf w^{(i)})  - \log P(\mathcal D \vert \mathbf w^{(i)}) \tag{2}\;\;?
$$

Comment: When minimizing, the $\frac{1}{n}$ is superfluous.

Comment: @Xi'an so the approximation, as written in equation (2), is "technically wrong" (i.e. notationally lazy), but makes no difference to optimization?